# C# Remove duplicated entries (but not keep first entries and second entries)

Tags: c#, mysql, list, distinct

Is it possible to remove all non unique values in list structure? If List contains these values

`11,9,8,7,6,5,4,10,8,7,6,5,4,2`.

But after removing duplicates it should be

`11,9,10,2`.

If I try to divide this list on half and than apply `List.Concat(List2).Disticnt()` values `8,7,6,5,4` are still in the List.

Answer (score 6):

```
var list = new List<int>() { 11, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2 };
var list2 = list.GroupBy(x => x)
                .Where(x => x.Count() == 1)
                .Select(x => x.First())
                .ToList();
```